# Gulps Ability for unit testing?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, gulp, jasmine, qunit

I'm newbie in gulp and I have some questions:

Is it possible to use gulp as unit testing in visual studio?

Is it any possibility to use gulp with Qunit, jasmine etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gulp is simple task runner. you can use it to define certain jobs to perform via single command.
here's one plugin that might help: 
https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma

and here's one article that might be interesting: 
https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/unit-test-03-basic-testing/

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I understand right, it is only used in the local computer? It sounds that gulps is similiar as powershell?

Comment: it can be used on any machine not only local machine just prerequisite are node js and gulp installed. and gulp is not Powershell. it is task runner which can automate your dev work by writing scripting tasks.

Comment: " it is task runner which can automate your dev work by writing scripting tasks" Do you have any concrete example from your experience?

Comment: yes so suppose what I want to do is when i build and deploy my web application to dev machine or production machine. i want to run  this task 1) combine all js file and css files in one file. 2) minify file and ulify them. 3) change refrences of this file path in html so that html pages can pick up this minified files. so for this all tasks i will write specific scripting task in gulp running one after other. hope you got it :)